# How can I setting OperatorStrokeElement?

Tags: python, scripting, sculpting

I try to deform the mesh by script.

In my past question, one of the answers is

> In sculpt mode, the operator used would be
> `bpy.ops.sculpt.brush_stroke`. Using that in a script will involve
> setting up an `OperatorStrokeElement` which would include mouse
> position...

But, I don't know how to set `OperatorStrokeElement`.
Please tell me how to set `OperatorStrokeElement`.
If possible, please give me an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
def context_override():
    for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
        screen = window.screen
        for area in screen.areas:
            if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                for region in area.regions:
                    if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                        return {'window': window, 'screen': screen, 'area': area, 
'region': region, 'scene': bpy.context.scene} 

bpy.ops.sculpt.brush_stroke(context_override(), stroke=strokes)
```

where "strokes" is a list of viewport coordinate-tuples, like `[(0,0,1),(0,0,-0.5),...]`

Source is [here](https://github.com/christian-vorhemus/procedural-3d-image-generation/blob/master/blenderBackgroundTask.py#L71).